# how to add kinit keytab inside the start up script

Tags: bash, shell

Sorry for this silly question, I need to add `kinit -kt /home/rxie/rxie.keytab rxie` to a script file so that when I run the script file, it will kinit with my keytab.
The kinit command is working fine in bash, but when I run the script, I got prompt saying grammar error near rxie

The script is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from jupyter_core.command import main

echo 'kinit -kt /home/rxie/rxie.keytab rxie'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to sort it out? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually caused by my confusion on shell scripting and python, what I really want to put in is a python script but I thought it is a shell script.

In python, all I need is to import os and then use os.system to run external command which is the kinit in this case.